# Complex newsletter with external subscribers and custom attachments

Tags: emails

I've created a Drupal 7 site for a financial company with approx. 60 employees. Only the employees are registered users.

The company has about 3000 customers that are registered in an external accounting system, with financial data for each customer. I have access to all customer data through soap 1.2 web services.

I have written a couple of custom modules that handles customer login, so that each customer can have access to an up to date report on their finacial status. I validate the login through a web service, and display their financial data also pulled from another web service to the accounting system. They can download the report as a PDF that is dynamically generated.

The company now wants to send a monthly report to each customer in email with the customers report attached as a PDF file. They have become quite comfortable with the drupal 7 admin interface and want to control when to send, see how many failed emails - essentially everything simplenews does.

Has anyone done anything similar? Only the admin interface is drupal based - I will need to provide the "subscribers" list and somehow link the "subscriber" with his/her correct PDF report. Also, customers come and go, so the subscriber list is ever changing.

I guess I could create a totally custom module solution, but I really would like to use existing email handling, etc from an existing newsletter module.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, in advance!